# Android - why does it return to the first activity

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I'm developing an chat app using Firebase as database.
In the app i have 3 activitys: LoginActivity,MainActivity and chatActivity.
In the MainActivity i can open a chat room and then enter to the chat room.
Then it opens the chatActivity.
On the chat activity the users can send message to each other. And here my problem is. When the user type a message and press send. for some reason when the user press the SEND button it jumps to the mainActivity instand send the message. i have no idea whats going on and i need your help guys.

**Main activity code**

```
    package com.world.bolandian.firebase;


 public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

private Button createChat;
private EditText chatRoomName;
private ListView listView;
private ArrayAdapter<String> arrayAdapter;
private ArrayList<String> listOfChats = new ArrayList<>();
private String name;
private DatabaseReference root  = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().getRoot();

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
       ifUserIsLoggedIn();

    createChat = (Button)findViewById(R.id.createChatBtn);
    chatRoomName = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.chatRoomEt);
    listView = (ListView)findViewById(R.id.listView);

    arrayAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,android.R.layout.simple_dropdown_item_1line, listOfChats);

    listView.setAdapter(arrayAdapter);

    enterUserName();

    createChat.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {

            Map<String, Object> map = new HashMap<String, Object>();
            map.put(chatRoomName.getText().toString(), "");
            root.updateChildren(map);
        }
    });

    root.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
        @Override
        public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {

            Set<String> set = new HashSet<String>();
            Iterator i = dataSnapshot.getChildren().iterator();

            while (i.hasNext()) {
                set.add(((DataSnapshot) i.next()).getKey());
            }
            listOfChats.clear();
            listOfChats.addAll(set);
            arrayAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
        }

        @Override
        public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {

        }
    });

    listView.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {

            Intent intent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(),ChatRoom.class);
            intent.putExtra("roomName",((TextView)view).getText().toString());
            intent.putExtra("userName",name);
            startActivity(intent);
        }
    });


      }


private void ifUserIsLoggedIn(){

    FirebaseAuth auth = FirebaseAuth.getInstance();
    FirebaseUser user = auth.getCurrentUser();
    if(user != null){

    }
    else
        startActivity(new Intent(this,LoginActivity.class));
}


    private void enterUserName(){

        AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
        builder.setTitle("Please enter A nick name:");

       final EditText input = new EditText(this);

        builder.setView(input);
        builder.setPositiveButton("OK", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                name = input.getText().toString();
            }
        });

        builder.setNegativeButton("Cancel", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                dialog.cancel();
                enterUserName();
            }
        });
        builder.show();
     }

   }
```

**This is ChatActivity**

```
  public class ChatRoom extends AppCompatActivity {

private Button sendMessageBtn;
private EditText inputMsg;
private TextView showMessage;
private DatabaseReference root;
private String userName,chatName,tempKey;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_chat_room);


    sendMessageBtn = (Button)findViewById(R.id.sendmessagebtn);
    inputMsg = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.messageEt);
    showMessage = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.showMessage);

    userName = getIntent().getExtras().get("userName").toString();
    chatName = getIntent().getExtras().get("roomName").toString();
    Log.v("username",userName);
    Log.v("chatname",chatName);

    setTitle(" Room " + chatName);

    root = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child(chatName);

    sendMessageBtn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            Map<String,Object> map = new HashMap<String, Object>();
            tempKey = root.push().getKey();
            root.updateChildren(map);

            DatabaseReference messageRoot = root.child(tempKey);
            Map<String,Object> map2 = new HashMap<String, Object>();
            map2.put("name",userName);
            map2.put("message",inputMsg);

            messageRoot.updateChildren(map2);
        }
    });


    root.addChildEventListener(new ChildEventListener() {
        @Override
        public void onChildAdded(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot, String s) {

            chatConversation(dataSnapshot);
        }

        @Override
        public void onChildChanged(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot, String s) {

            chatConversation(dataSnapshot);
        }

        @Override
        public void onChildRemoved(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {

        }

        @Override
        public void onChildMoved(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot, String s) {

        }

        @Override
        public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {

        }
    });

}

private String chatMsg,chatUserName;

private void chatConversation(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot){

    Iterator i = dataSnapshot.getChildren().iterator();
        while(i.hasNext()){
            chatMsg = (String)((DataSnapshot)i.next()).getValue();
            chatUserName = (String)((DataSnapshot)i.next()).getValue();

            showMessage.append(chatUserName + " : " + chatMsg +"\n" );
        }
    }
 }
```

---

Thats the code guys

Comment: Assuming that you activity is crashing for some reason and its returning to the previous activity (which is your main activity). check your logcat, is there any error?

Comment: " W/DynamiteModule: Local module descriptor class for com.google.firebase.auth not found."   could be that the error?

Answer (score 0):

Finally i have found my mistake.

```
        DatabaseReference messageRoot = root.child(tempKey);
        Map<String,Object> map2 = new HashMap<String, Object>();
        map2.put("name",userName);
        map2.put("message",inputMsg); -- thats the line that crash the app

       **map2.put("message",inputMsg.getText().toString());** should be like that

        messageRoot.updateChildren(map2);
```